# Fully reinstall / remove VIM

Tags: vim, linux-mint

I recently ran a script which configures VIM and installs plugins needed for development. I installed it like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles.git
$ cd dotfiles
$ ./install.sh vim
```

I don't understand any of plugins and now I want to remove everything I did.

I basically want a fresh install of VIM so I can configure it by myself and understand everything.

How should I do this? I'm using Linux Mint LXDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running the following commands in a shell:

`sudo apt-get purge vim && sudo apt-get install vim`

This completely removes vim, including all configuration files, and installs it again.

Comment: This did it, my .vimrc reappeared and I was able to clear it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to remove `.vim/` folder and `.vimrc` when I tried it